# android Wifi direct simultaneous membership

Tags: android, wifi-direct

Does android P2p device supports p2p simultaneous membership?
I have three device A,B,C. 
A is the Group owner, B is a P2p client and together form a group.
I need B performs a new group negotiation with C.

Comment: While Google claim it is SUPPOSED to, I could never get it to work. I was always overriding the first socket connection with the one after.

Answer (score 0):

If B is connected to a group it can't connect to C.  However, C should be able to connect to either A or B and join the existing group.